# Can't seem to star a chat message

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat

I wanted to star a chat message: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14090701#14090701

Is this reputation based? At the time of this question I had 261 reputation. Or is it the fact that I'm trying to star it almost a day after it was said?

FYI: I'm trying to star it in the actual chatroom, not the transcript. I do see a star and a flag when I hover over the message, but when I click on the star, nothing happens.

Update: I was able to do it in chrome, but not in firefox

Update 2: I am able to reproduce consistently in Firefox 27.0.1 in code golf's chat, but not in stack overflow's chat. It works chrome in both sites.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Updated the question. The latter, but I did have to click "load older messages" one time.

Comment: I can star it just fine...

Answer (score 1):

So I starred that message using Chrome, and then when I tried to reproduce it again in Firefox, I could not. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Could just be a cookie issue. Earlier I was logged into SE but Chat believed I wasn't despite repeated attempts at signing out and in. Eventually had to wipe SE cookies and log in again, then chat worked fine. Pretty common thing with web applications - state can easily be corrupted.